# Compiler Can't create SqlConnection instance when getting string from file

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I have created a Windows Forms application and I am getting data from my database in it, but I have a problem: the `SqlConnection` object cannot be instantiated.

When I declare this connection string, it works:

```
static string connectionString = "Data Source=DEVELOPMENT-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=True";
```

But when I retrieve this from textfile, it doesn't work:

```
static string a = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]), "connectionString.txt")).ToString();
```

One point: when I write `MessageBox.Show(a);`,  I see in the window the same string as connection string shown above is.

What could be the problem?

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't really describe the problem, what is the error you are getting? Do you have two `\\` in the text file (you should only have one!)? The text file should look like this: Data Source=DEVELOPMENT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=True - notice the single slash.

Comment: Ron Beyer, it solved my problem.. Why I need to write here two \\, and in textfile - one \ symbol?

Comment: I think I guess,.. compiler needs to see \ as \, two \\, is it right?

Comment: Because you are escaping the slashes in C#, the text file doesn't require escaping the string. For example a string like "This is my\nstring" in C# is two lines, if you want the same effect in a text file you just write it on two lines. The slash is the start of an escape sequence, by writing \\ you are telling it to ignore it and use a single slash in its place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is actually that you have two slashes in the text file. The string is escaped in C# but does not need to be escaped in the text file. The C# is like this:

```
"Data Source=DEVELOPMENT-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=True"
```

Where the text file should just have a single slash:

```
Data Source=DEVELOPMENT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=True
```

This is because you are escaping the slashes in C#, the text file doesn't require escaping the string. For example a string like `"This is my\nstring"` in C# is two lines, if you want the same effect in a text file you just write it on two lines. The slash is the start of an escape sequence, by writing \ you are telling it to ignore it and use a single slash in its place.

If you only want a single slash in the C# code, you can do that too:

```
static string connectionString = @"Data Source=DEVELOPMENT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=True";
```

Here the `@` symbol tells the compiler that the following string does not contain any escape sequences and to treat it as a literal. This makes it easier especially when working with file paths so you don't have to escape all the slashes.

Comment: @Beginner I updated the answer to show how to avoid escaping the slashes in C# code as well, to make things easier.